# Let $a_n = \frac{n^p}{e^n}$ Show that $a_n$ converges for all $p>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

In my work on this problem I've set up a limit:
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^p}{e^x}\right)$$

I can see that for any number of p, successive applications of L'Hopital's Rule will eventually bring the numerator to a finite number, if p is an integer. If p is a fraction successive applications of L'Hopital's rule will eventually bring the $x$ term from the numerator to the denominator. Therefore in each case the limit will equal zero because the denominator's $e^x$ term will still be the same.

How do I express this logic in math form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can take $f(y)=y^\frac{1}{p}$ and apply it to your quantity.  You can then use continuity of f and its inverse to use l'hopital's rule once.  i.e.  use L'hopitals rule on $\frac{x}{e^{x/p}}$ then raise it to the power of p and use the fact that $y^p$ is continuous so that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(\frac{x}{e^{x/p}})^p=\left(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(\frac{x}{e^{x/p}})\right)^p$

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

- If $p\in\mathbb Z^{+}$

$$\begin{align}\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^p}{e^x}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{p!}{e^x}=0.\end{align}$$

---

- If $p>0, p\in\mathbb R^{+}$

$$0≤\left(\frac{x^p}{e^x}\right)≤\left(\frac{x^{\lceil p \rceil}}{e^x}\right)$$

Then apply the Squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ N \in \mathbb N$ such that $N \ge p.$ For $x>1$ we get with the Taylor series of $e^x$:

$$e^x > \frac{x^{N+1}}{(N+1)!} \ge \frac{x^{p+1}}{(N+1)!} .$$

Thus

$$\frac{e^x}{x^p} \ge \frac{x}{(N+1)!},$$

hence

$$0 \le \frac{x^p}{e^x} \le \frac{(N+1)!}{x}.$$

This gives

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^p}{e^x}=0.$$